# Is there a mathematical way to determine the bond angles in a molecule without using the standard VSEPR model?

Tags: bond

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to mathematically determine the bond angles in a molecule without using the standard VSEPR model. I was curious if such a thing exists.

Comment: It doesn't.$\;$

Comment: You would have to do a complicated molecular orbital calculation using software such as Gaussian. That is of course, 'mathematical' solving the Schroedinger equation but probably not in the sense you are thinking of. For small molecules the Walsh rules give an indication of what bond angles should be.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, I will definitely check that out, I'm a chem/math major and would rather use something more calculation based than Lewis Structures.

Comment: That may not be right. Being good at chemistry (as with other sciences) frequently involves knowing when a very simple model will give you essentially the answer you need without the using a more complicated model.